# Converting a Java XStream object to XML, XSD or JAXB (without sample data)

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xstream

I have a Java object that uses XStream to convert the object from XML to a java object and vice versa.

I know how to convert the Java object to an XML document but i don't know how to do this without having to initialize the attributes in the XStream object. I.e. if the attribute is not initialised XStream does not generate the XML tag when it generates the XML.

What i would like to do is to generate an XSD from that Java object and to be able to do that i need an XML version of the object containing all the possible tags.

I cant really initialize each individual attribute because the XStream object has hundreds of attributes with several child attributes (i.e. a very complex structure).

Is it possible to generate the XML from an XStream object that contains all the possible tags (probably with randomized data) without having to initialize all the attributes in the XStream object?

It is probably programmable but i will have to iterate through each attribute, and each attribute's attribute and each attribute's attribute's attribute (you get the picture) to try and work out what all the tags are :)

### Edit

I am also thinking that if it is possible to convert the XStream object to a JAXB object i might be able to generate the XSD as i understand it is easier to generate an XSD from JAXB. Is this the easier approach?

Comment: "What i would like to do is to generate an XSD from that Java object and to be able to do that i need an XML version of the object containing all the possible tags. " This isn't true. The program schemagen that comes with JAXB is capable of creating an XML Schema from Java classes. Works well, if the classes aren't too far off from what works well with JAXB. (Java and XML are rather different.)

Comment: Presumably schemagen requires that the Java object to be in JAXB format?

Comment: There is no special "JAXB format" for the classes. Beans style is good. JAXB annotations may help to distinguish elements and attributes. List is the preferred collection type.

Comment: I was not aware that schemagen can process non JAXB objects. I will try it thanks.

Comment: Also, using JAXB annotations on classes you can marshal and unmarshal without an XML Schema. See my JAXB tutorial: https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/